# Use one primary key as two foreign key in two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hibernate

My requirement is to make ManytoMany relation between provinces-languages and cities-languages.

So i did like this

**Provinces**
 PK:id,
    name

**Languages**
PK:id,
name

**Provinces_Languages**
province_id
languages_id

Similarly for cities:

**Cities**
PK:id,
name

**Using same Languages Table**

**Cities_Languages**
cities_id
languages_id

Now , i want to make oneToMany/ManytoOne relation between provinces and cities

**Provinces**
PK:id,
name

**Cities**
PK:id,
name

Here i have problem in understanding that how i connect both of them?
because **provinces** "id" is already used by the **Provinces_Languages** as foreign key.
and **Cities** "id" is also used by the **Cities_Languages** as foreign key

Please guide me how i link up these entities?

Comment: YOU may also need a many to many relationship.  I don't know what country you are modeling, but I do know in the US, there are some cites which cross state lines. So before deciding what to do, I would check for this condition, a city in multiple provinces.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem there - add `provinces_id` to your **Cities** table and make it a foreign key for **Provinces**.id.

Answer (score 0):

You actually could combine the `Provinces_Languages` and `Cities_Languages` tables into one.  Just need to add a `type` field.  See the below example ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/181a1/17/0)):

```
CREATE TABLE Provinces(id int auto_increment primary key, 
                       name varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE Cities(id int auto_increment primary key, 
                    name varchar(100),
                    prov_id int);

CREATE TABLE Languages(id int auto_increment primary key, 
                       name varchar(100));

CREATE TABLE ProvCity_Languages(provcity_id int, 
                                languages_id int,
                                type varchar(10));

INSERT INTO Provinces (name) VALUES
('Province1'),('Province2');

INSERT INTO Cities (name, prov_id) VALUES
('City1', 1),('City2', 1),('City3', 2),('City4', 2);

INSERT INTO Languages (name) VALUES
('English'),('Spanish'),('French'),
('Chinese'),('Pig Latin');

INSERT INTO ProvCity_Languages 
(provcity_id, languages_id, type) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 1),(2, 1, 1),(1, 4, 2),
(2, 1, 2),(3, 1, 2),(3, 2, 2),(4, 5, 2),
(4, 4, 2),(4, 3, 2);

SELECT p.name AS ProvName, c.name AS CityName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pll.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS ProvLang,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cll.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS CityLang
FROM Provinces p
  JOIN Cities c on p.id = c.prov_id
  JOIN ProvCity_Languages pl on p.id = pl.provcity_id AND pl.type = 1 
  JOIN Languages pll on pl.languages_id = pll.id
  JOIN ProvCity_Languages cl on c.id = cl.provcity_id AND cl.type = 2
  JOIN Languages cll on cl.languages_id = cll.id
GROUP BY p.name, c.name
```

I showed the above SELECT query just to show you that you can do whatever you want with the results.  The result would be something like the following:

[image]